# change the image after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the image after refresh the page, but it doesn't work

Here is the javascript part

```
<script>
  var theImages = [
      "../images/casblanca.jpg",
      "../images/casblanca2.jpg",
      "../images/spot.jpg";
  ];
  function changeImage(){
  var size=theImages.length;
  var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
  document.getElementById("spotlight").src = theImages[x];
}
</script>
```

Here is the html main part

```
  <nav class="spot" onload="changeImage()">
      <h1>SPOTLIGHT</h1>
      <a href="play.html"><img id="spotlight" width="1000" height="600" alt=""></a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) You are using** and extra semi colon (;)

> "../images/spot.jpg";

at the end of your last image. Go ahead and delete it.

**2) Use the onload event in the body tag.**

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
 var theImages = [
        "http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/25-cars-worth-waiting-for-lp-ford-gt-photo-658253-s-original.jpg",
        "https://carfromjapan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/5-Best-Rated-Cars-of-2016.jpg",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TzcS7Mcq2oA/maxresdefault.jpg"
    ];
    function changeImage(){
        var size=theImages.length;
        var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
        document.getElementById("spotlight").src = theImages[x];
    }
```

```html
<body onload="changeImage()">

<nav class="spot">
    <h1>SPOTLIGHT</h1>
    <a href="play.html"><img id="spotlight" width="1000" height="600" alt=""></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` attribute is not supported on the `<nav>` element. Try it on the `<body>`

There is also a syntax error in your image array. An unnecessary semicolon.

See working example below:

```js
  var theImages = [
  "https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/fff&text=Image+1",
  "https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/f0f&text=Image+2",
  "https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/ff0&text=Image+3"
  ];
  function changeImage(){
  var size=theImages.length;
  var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
  document.getElementById("spotlight").src = theImages[x];
}
```

```html
<body onload="changeImage()">
  <nav class="spot" >
  <h1>SPOTLIGHT</h1>
  <a href="play.html"><img id="spotlight" width="1000" height="600" alt=""></a>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate `CSS`, `JS` and `HTML`.

Declare the varibles as

```
var theImages = [],
  size, x;
```

Remove the onload() function.
Rewrite the random function as the following.

> x = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).
Here [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) always return a value among 0,1,2.

Rewrite the code as the following.

```
size = theImages.length;
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
document.getElementById("spotlight").src = theImages[x];
```

```js
var theImages = [],
  size, x;
theImages = [
  "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_car.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"
];
size = theImages.length;
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
document.getElementById("spotlight").src = theImages[x];
```

```css
#spotlight {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<h1>SPOTLIGHT</h1>
<a href="#"><img id="spotlight" alt=""></a>
```